# Computing modular inverses $65537^{-1\!}\bmod (10^n\!-1)$ for large $n$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have the following formula:
$$d \cdot 65537 \equiv 1 \pmod{9999...}$$
I have to find $d$, even in case the modulo is 30 digits long.

This means I am not supposed to brute force it, but I haven't yet come across to anything that would help me with this matter.

I thought cryptography uses modulo exactly because this problem is hard to solve. Can you give a hint on how to approach this problem?
I think the 65537 prime is supposed to help in some way, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Your solution can't be unique: if $d_1$ is such a solution, then so is $d_2=d_1+9999999...$.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.   Note $2^{16}=65536$

Comment: The Euclidean algoirthm works well, even if one of the terms is quite large.

Comment: So you need to find such $d$ so that $d\left(2^{16}+1\right) + 1 = 10^k$ for some integer $k$

Comment: To be clear:  $30$ digits is not especially big for the euclidean algorithm.  [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Bezout%5B2%5E16%2B1,10%5E30-1%5D) is able to handle it almost instantaneously.